# pagination is not working in codeignitor framework

Tags: codeigniter

I am new in Codeigniter. I am creating pagination in codeigniter, but paging number not working.

This is my record where i want pagination

[image]

when i click on paging link i got this type error.

[image]

Here is my controller code

```
public function benadharStatus($rowno=0) { 
          $this->load->library("pagination");

        if ($this->session->userdata('session_name')) {
            $data = array();
            $data = array('title' => 'Beneficiaries Aadhaar Status', 'pageTitle' => 'Beneficiaries Aadhaar Status');
            $obj = new Admin_model;
            $obj1 = new Reporting_model;
            $data['states'] = $obj->getState();
            if($_POST){
                      // Row per page
        $rowperpage = 25;

        // Row position
        if($rowno != 0){
            $rowno = ($rowno-1) * $rowperpage;
        }

        // All records count
        $allcount = $obj1->getBenficzReportOLD($_POST);

        // Get  records
        $users_record = $obj1->getBenficzReports($_POST,'1',$rowno,$rowperpage);

        // Pagination Configuration
        $config['base_url'] = base_url().'benadharStatus';
        $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
        $config['total_rows'] = $allcount;
        $config['per_page'] = $rowperpage;
                $config['uri_segment'] = 5;
        // Initialize
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);

        $data['links'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
        $data['benficirz'] = $users_record;
        $data['row'] = $rowno;

                $data['passed_state']=$this->input->post('ben_state');
                $data['passed_district']=$this->input->post('ben_district');
                $data['passed_awc']=$this->input->post('ben_awc');

                $data['flag']=1;
            }else{
              $data['flag']=2;  
            }
            $this->load->view('reports/benadharStatus', $data);
        } else {
            redirect('admin');
        }
    }
```

Guys please help... Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the name of your controller? You are missing the controller in `$config['base_url']`. It should be `$config['base_url'] = base_url().'<controller_name>/benadharStatus';`

Comment: my $config['base_url']='localhost:8081/codeigniter'

Answer (score 0):

Please try this replace this code:

```
public function benadharStatus($rowno=0) { 
      $this->load->library("pagination");

    if ($this->session->userdata('session_name')) {
        $data = array();
        $data = array('title' => 'Beneficiaries Aadhaar Status', 'pageTitle' => 'Beneficiaries Aadhaar Status');
        $obj = new Admin_model;
        $obj1 = new Reporting_model;
        $data['states'] = $obj->getState();
        if($_POST){
                  // Row per page
    $rowperpage = 25;

    // Row position
    if($rowno != 0){
        $rowno = ($rowno-1) * $rowperpage;
    }

    // All records count
    $allcount = $obj1->getBenficzReportOLD($_POST);

    // Get  records
    $users_record = $obj1->getBenficzReports($_POST,'1',$rowno,$rowperpage);

    // Pagination Configuration
    $controler_name = $this->router->fetch_class(); 
    $config['base_url'] = base_url().'/'.$controler_name.'/benadharStatus';
    $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
    $config['total_rows'] = $allcount;
    $config['per_page'] = $rowperpage;
            $config['uri_segment'] = 5;
    // Initialize
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    $data['links'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
    $data['benficirz'] = $users_record;
    $data['row'] = $rowno;

            $data['passed_state']=$this->input->post('ben_state');
            $data['passed_district']=$this->input->post('ben_district');
            $data['passed_awc']=$this->input->post('ben_awc');

            $data['flag']=1;
        }else{
          $data['flag']=2;  
        }
        $this->load->view('reports/benadharStatus', $data);
    } else {
        redirect('admin');
    }
}
```